# Passar valor de select para rota em laravel

Tags: php, javascript, html-select, laravel-5.3, laravel-rotas

Não sei muita coisa de desenvolvimento web e estou meio perdido. Eu preciso passar o id de um filme para uma rota em laravel e não estou sabendo como pegar esse valor.

```
<select class="form-control" style="width: 20%"  onchange="" id="select" name="filme">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Selecione um filme</option>
    @foreach($filmes as $f)
      <option value="{{$f->id}}">{{$f->nome}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
<?php echo $var = pegaId(); ?>
<br><br>
  <button type="submit" class="w3-btn-block" onclick="window.location='/filmes/{{$var}}'">Ver eventos</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function pegaId(){
    return document.getElementById('select');
  }
</script>
```

Eu li que não tem como atribuir o retorno de uma função JS à uma variável php pois o JavaScript roda do lado do cliente e o PHP do lado do servidor, então a minha variável não reconhece o retorno da função nesse momento. É isso mesmo?

Quando faço a chamada da função `pegaId()` da o erro

> Call to undefined function pegaId()

Eu acredito que tenha uma forma mais fácil de fazer isso, como chamar a função JS na minha url mas não estou conseguindo :(

Comment: Da onde vem a informação? é da `array de $filmes`? por que o que você fez me parece quase certo mas, `{{$var}}` vem da onde?

Comment: está abaixo do select, eu tento fazer uma chamada para função pegaId() mas da o erro `Call to undefined function pegaId()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso que o que deseja é algo do género:

Vista:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('selecionar.filme') }}">
{{csrf_field() }}

<select class="form-control" style="width: 20%"  onchange="" id="select" name="filme">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Selecione um filme</option>
    @foreach($filmes as $f)
      <option value="{{$f->id}}">{{$f->nome}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<br><br>
  <button type="submit" class="w3-btn-block">Ver eventos</button>
</form>
```

Route:

```
Route::post('selecionarFilme', ["as" => 'selecionar.filme', 'uses' => "FilmeController@store"]);
```

Controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $selecao = $request->get('select');

        return redirect('filmes/'.$selecao);
}
```

Comment: Só uma dúvida: a chamada `FilmeController@selecionar` está certa? Não seria `FilmeController@store`? E o que está sendo feito nessa linha `dd($selecao)`

Comment: O nome do método é "indiferente", mas claro que pode utilizar o nome store :)

Comment: Peço perdão, uma vez que o método que coloquei chama-se _store_ terá que ser `FilmeController@store`. Ou então mudar o nome do método para _selecionar_

Comment: Eu não entendi como posso usar o retorno da função store e redirecionar para a página `filmes/{{$var}}`. Eu quero que, ao clicar no botão, o usuário seja redirecionado para essa página

Comment: Editei a resposta de forma a responder a essa questão.